# Stored Procedures that creates a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can I create tables using Stored Procedures?

I am using MySQL. I had searched the web for instructions on how to create a table using stored procedure, but I didn't find any results, I just found that you can create temporary tables. Is there any problem if I create tables using stored procedures?

Actually I want to check whether a table exists or not, then I have to create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create tables using procedures in mysql.

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_TABLE_TEST ()
   BEGIN
      CREATE TABLE TEST 
      (
        TestID int(11) default NULL,
        TestName varchar(100) default NULL
      ) 
      ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
   END;

|
```

[Reference link.](http://www.php-example.com/2011/04/creating-table-using-mysql-stored.html)

Comment: can we give constraints also..?

Comment: hwo to run this stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

---

EDIT: Thanks Peter! So the solution to this particular problem:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE createTable(IN tableName VARCHAR(40))
BEGIN
SET @table := tableName;
SET @sql_text:=CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',@table,'(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, FILENAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, DATA BLOB NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))');

PREPARE stmt from @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

In addition to the manual I also found a very helpful tut by Roland Bouman at:

http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html`enter code here`

El autor de la respuesta: Conrad Ljungström

link de la respuesta original: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,495352

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in a stored procedure without a problem. Example:

```
delimiter |

create procedure createtab () 
begin 
    create table a(id int);
    insert into a select 1;
    select * from a;
    drop table a;
end
|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: hwo to run this stored procedure.

Comment: @paul: `call createtab()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_TABLE( )
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE employees (emp_id int, emp_name varchar(100));
END;
|
```

Comment: hwo to run this stored procedure.